# Image Gallery animation

Tags: jquery, gallery, image-gallery

I am currently working on a video thumbnail gallery that has two rows of 5 images for a total of 10 images. The functionality is the user clicks on the video thumb and a ios folder like animation happens and within the opened area is the video with some info. I currently have half of it working but I am having a hard time figuring out the functionality for the bottom row. I would like when a user clicks on the second row of video thumbs the area opens up above the video which it does but the problem is the bottom is out of view and I am trying to figure out how to move up the bottom video window when you click on one of the bottom row images if possible. Here is a link to what I have so far :http://jsfiddle.net/jsavage/Vnya7/33/[question]. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you cant see the bottom row when it animates is because `.container` has a set height of 410px and overflow set to be hidden. Removing these will fix that problem. Here's an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yfcdD/